# Как сделать ответ пользователю который находится в белом списке?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Имеется следующий код. Как сделать чтобы пользователю который находится в белом списке бот присылал какое-нибудь сообщение?

```
import telebot

token = 'токен'
adm = 'айди'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

whitelist = [айди,айди,айди]

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in whitelist)
def some(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы не находитесь в Whitelist!")

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in whitelist)
def some(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы находитесь в Whitelist!")
```

Comment: Это работает, спасибо.